# VKRequest after VKSdk.authorize() throws error "invalid user id". One after another?

Tags: android, api, authentication, vk

I make a request to get user profile info by clicking `Button`. I debugged and when I just opened app and clicked on button `onError` callback worked and it said "invalid user id". If I press `Button` second time it works fine. From experiments I understood that app didn't complete authorization, that's why request was denied.
By pressing `Button` calls method with this code:

```
VKSdk.authorize(VKScopes.EMAIL);
VKRequest request = VKApi.users().get(VKParameters.from(VKApiConst.FIELDS,
    "user_id,first_name,last_name,sex,bdate,city,photo_200_orig"));
request.secure = false;
request.useSystemLanguage = true;
request.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {
     @Override
     public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
         super.onComplete(response);
         //do some stuff
     }
     @Override
     public void attemptFailed(VKRequest request, int attemptNumber, int totalAttempts) {
          super.attemptFailed(request, attemptNumber, totalAttempts);
          Log.d("VkDemoApp", "attemptFailed " + request + " " + attemptNumber + " " + totalAttempts);
    }
    @Override
    public void onError(VKError error) {
         super.onError(error);
         Log.d("VkDemoApp", "onError: " + error);
    }
    @Override
    public void onProgress(VKRequest.VKProgressType progressType, long bytesLoaded, long bytesTotal) {
         super.onProgress(progressType, bytesLoaded, bytesTotal);
         Log.d("VkDemoApp", "onProgress " + progressType + " " + bytesLoaded + " " + bytesTotal);
    }
});
```

I tried to add `if(VKSdk.wakeUpSession())` , but it simply passed through, cuz user is not authorized yet. I found in example callback `onTokenExpired` as part of `listener`, where I'll authorize user if needed, but when I added it said "is never used".

How can I wait until `VKSdk.authorize()` finish working and only after send request?
Thanks in advance!

*EDIT*

This is the line in `onCreate()`

```
VKSdk.initialize(sdkListener, activity.getResources().getString(R.string.vk_app_id));
VKUIHelper.onCreate(this);
```

*VKSdkListener*

```
VKSdkListener sdkListener = new VKSdkListener() {
    @Override
    public void onAcceptUserToken(VKAccessToken token) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceiveNewToken(VKAccessToken newToken) {
        //requesting the code at the top (request)
        //excluding the line VKSdk.authorize(VKScopes.EMAIL);
    }

    @Override
    public void onRenewAccessToken(VKAccessToken token) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onCaptchaError(VKError vkError) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onTokenExpired(VKAccessToken vkAccessToken) {
    }
    @Override
    public void onAccessDenied(VKError vkError) {
    }
};
```

and in `onClick()` there is a line `VKSdk.authorize(VKScopes.EMAIL);`

*NOTE* VkSdkListener's callbacks are not being called after `initialize()`, but called after `authorize()`. I don't know why, the behavior of this is awful. Would be great to see working example with gotten user's email and other things listed above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I could be wrong, but try to change "user_id" to "id". 
The answer to your second question (how to fetch data after authorize) is simple.
VKsdk has a listener with abstract methods that you could (and should) override.

EDIT

```
private static final String[] sVkontakteScopes = new String[]{
        VKScope.FRIENDS,
        VKScope.PHOTOS,
        VKScope.NOHTTPS,
};

private VKSdkListener mVkontakteLoginListener;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState, persistentState);

    mVkontakteLoginListener = new VKSdkListener() {
        @Override
        public void onCaptchaError(VKError captchaError) {
            new VKCaptchaDialog(captchaError).show(VkApiActivity.this);
        }

        @Override
        public void onTokenExpired(VKAccessToken expiredToken) {
            VKSdk.authorize(sVkontakteScopes);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAccessDenied(VKError authorizationError) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(VKUIHelper.getTopActivity())
                    .setMessage(authorizationError.toString())
                    .show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onReceiveNewToken(VKAccessToken newToken) {
            //put your method here
            makeYourStuff();
            PrefUtils.storeVkontakteAccessToken(newToken.accessToken);
        }

        @Override
        public void onAcceptUserToken(VKAccessToken token) {
            //put your method here
            makeYourStuff();
        }

        @Override
        public void onRenewAccessToken(VKAccessToken token) {
            //put your method here
            makeYourStuff();
        }
    };

    if (PrefUtils.getVkontakteAccessToken() != null)
        VKSdk.initialize(mVkontakteLoginListener, getString(R.string.vkontakte_app_id, PrefUtils.getVkontakteAccessToken()));
    else {
        VKSdk.initialize(mVkontakteLoginListener, getString(R.string.vkontakte_app_id));
    }
    VKUIHelper.onCreate(this);
}


private void makeYourStuff() {
    VKParameters params = new VKParameters();
    params.put(VKApiConst.FIELDS, "id,first_name,last_name, photo_100");

    VKRequest request = new VKRequest("users.get", params);
    request.executeWithListener(new VKRequest.VKRequestListener() {

        @Override
        public void onComplete(VKResponse response) {
            super.onComplete(response);
            JSONArray jsonArray;
            String firstName, lastName, id, photoUrl;


            try {
                jsonArray = response.json.getJSONArray("response");
                JSONObject userObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                firstName = userObject.getString("first_name");
                lastName = userObject.getString("last_name");
                id = userObject.getString("id");
                photoUrl = userObject.getString("photo_100");

                /*
                    here you can start another activity or fragment

                    put this info into bundle or store into database

                */
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onError(VKError error) {
            super.onError(error);
        }
    });
}

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    VKUIHelper.onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v.getId() == R.id.btnLogin) {
        VKSdk.authorize(sVkontakteScopes);
        // after this method will be called your one of your          VKSdkListener methods
        // you should put your request method all three SUCCESS methods of VKSdk listener
    }
}
```

Comment: Hm... I haven't seen that listener before... I'll check it out and respond later. Thank you!

Comment: You should use this listener when initialize VkSDK, something like that:
VKSdk.initialize(mVKSdkListener, vk_app_id) or second version (if u've got token) VKSdk.initialize(mVKSdkListener, vk_app_id, token)

Comment: with initialization I don't have any problems. I initialize it in onCreate() and it is fine. The problem is the autorize() and request are being sent almost at the same time

Comment: Yeap, just try to implement my answer and reply about result

Comment: I've just checked my code. I had this listener before, in onCreate(), but I implemented there only abstract callbacks. I did follow your idea, but it didn't help me for some reason. I still have to press second time on button to login, because the request did not respond me anything after that... I think your answer makes point, but still didn't figure out how people do that. That's basics actually, but... but...

Comment: To figure where is problem share full code of your activity.

Comment: this is really good answer. Seems I had to not follow docs, but your code seems is correct and right solution... Anyways, I accept your answer and upvote it. Thank you for help!